# How to update a UITableView that after NSUserdefaults settings have been changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm wondering how to best update a UITableView. I have a settings area where the user can save preferences (saved to NSUserDefaults). Then when they come back to the table view the list of data needs to be updated to reflect the settings/prefs changes the user has made.

At the moment I have the simply have `[self.tableView reloadData];`
 in the viewWillAppear: method

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind a best way to reload  your table.
if you want to reload one row(or more), you can use

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:];
```

if you want to do multiple inserts or delete you can use

```
 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

`[self.tableView reloadData];` reload everything...redisplays visible rows, reloads data.